# return 1 row instead of multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a query which is currently returning me 4 rows.

```
SELECT (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0 
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as paidWithDelay,
        (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0 
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as Overdue,
        (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0  
        then count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as paidOnTime,
        (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0  
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as waitingForPayment
        FROM payment_plan a
        where a.payor_orig_id = 611 and a.UPDATE_DT is null
        group by a.duedate;
```

Like this in the picture.[image]
Basically what I want is to return just one row
Like this
`paidWithDelay 2 , overdue 1 , paidontime 0 and waitingForPayment 1 ,`
I tried writing sum front of case , but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select sum(paidwithdelay)paidwithydelay,sum(overdue)overdue,sum(paidontime)paidontime,sum(waitingforpayment)waitingforpayment 
from (SELECT (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0 
            then  count(a.duedate)
            else 0 end) as paidWithDelay,
            (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0 
            then  count(a.duedate)
            else 0 end) as Overdue,
            (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0  
            then count(a.duedate)
            else 0 end) as paidOnTime,
            (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0  
            then  count(a.duedate)
            else 0 end) as waitingForPayment
            FROM payment_plan a
            where a.payor_orig_id = 611 and a.UPDATE_DT is null
            group by a.duedate)temp;
```

Comment: this works, but I get the column names as sum(paidwithdelay) , sum(overdue) , is there any way to remove that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select sum(paidWithDelay), 
       sum(Overdue), 
       sum(paidOnTime), 
       sum(waitingForPayment)
from 
(
    SELECT (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0 
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as paidWithDelay,
        (case when a.duedate < '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0 
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as Overdue,
        (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid > 0  
        then count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as paidOnTime,
        (case when a.duedate > '2016-04-26' and a.total_paid = 0  
        then  count(a.duedate)
        else 0 end) as waitingForPayment
    FROM payment_plan a
    where a.payor_orig_id = 611 and a.UPDATE_DT is null
    group by a.duedate
) t1;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias, This is what I get when I try your code.

Comment: should add the temp table at the end, above query will give you error

Comment: Thanks ! For both of your answer :) 
I will choose @Priyanshu updated answer .